# Problem with function mutate_if together with function auto.arima

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying create a table that receive data from of a function `auto.arima`.

I am using the mutate_if in my code, but it does not work.

Here is what I tried.

Function Auto.arima

```
FunArima<- function(x){ 
  arima <- auto.arima(x)
  previsao <- forecast(arima, h=12)
  plot(previsao)
  previsao
  }
FunArima(Base$a)
```

---

Mutate_IF

```
df <- Base [2:5]
df1 <- df %>%
mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) FunArima)
```

My problem is? I need to do a arima model to each column in my table.

data Base:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your function `FunArima`does not return a vector of the same length as`x` but an object of type `forecast`.
What you can do is to adjust the function call inside `mutate_if` so that only the forecast is returned:

```
tibble(year = 2010 : 2017, x = c(1,1,2,5,4,3,2,1), y = c(2,3,3,6,6,4,4,2)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-"year"), ~FunArima(.x)$fitted)
```

Also note that I rather use `mutate_at` instead of `mutate_if` since the latter would select all columns in this case and I guess you want to exclude the year column for this exercise.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Cettt. I got like you said.